Can't import keras.preprocessing and keras.models
the library is installed, everything is downloaded, but the program considers these lines as a             syntax error. how to fix this, please help, the program does not work and does not start. Also functions through tf.keras do not work
here is the code itself:
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np

# Загрузка модели
model = load_model('museum_exponat_classifier.h5')

# Путь к вашему изображению
img_path = 'F:\\test2\\IMG_4903.JPG'

# Загрузка и предварительная обработка изображения
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))  # Изменение размера изображения
img_array = image.img_to_array(img)  # Преобразование в массив
img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)  # Добавление оси для батча
img_array = img_array / 255.0  # Нормализация пикселей

# Прогнозирование
predictions = model.predict(img_array)
predicted_class = np.argmax(predictions)  # Определение индекса предсказанного класса

# Опционально: Распознавание классов
# Если классы были известны из генератора данных, нужно подгрузить информацию о них
class_indices = {'class_1': 0, 'class_2': 1, 'class_3': 2, 'class_4': 3, 'class_5': 4,'class_6':       5, 'class_7': 6}  # Пример
classes = {v: k for k, v in class_indices.items()}  # Инвертируем словарь

# Вывод предсказанного класса
predicted_label = classes[predicted_class]
print(f"Предсказанный класс: {predicted_label}")


here is the error itself:
PS C:\Users\dimas> & C:/Users/dimas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe d:/test3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\test3.py", line 1, in 
from keras_models import load_model
ImportError: cannot import name 'load_model' from 'keras_models' (C:\Users\dimas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras_models_init_.py)
PS C:\Users\dimas>

Better check step by step on python interpreter:
import keras
import keras.models
to see what's wrong and where it stucks. Can you provide too the version of keras installed.

You need to include the full traceback in the question, edit your question, not as a comment
